# Linear Equalizer LMS algorithm

Tags: digital-communications

I have to realise a Linear Spaced Equalizer using LMS algorithm on Matlab by writing the code from this [image: [diagram][1] (open the link).]

The algorithm to be implemented is iterative. It starts with an initial value (initialisation) for example with all taps set to 0 except the middle one at 1. When training begins, the values of the taps move from the initial value to convergence. That is, at a certain point the values no longer change (I mean this by stabilisation).
I do not understand how to realise this.

How do I implement that 'switch' indicated by the red arrow in the diagram I attached from tracking to training sequence?

In reception with the cross correlation I have already managed to split the data from the training sequence from the received frame ... and then what?

Comment: And what is the relation of this homework to electrical engineering?

Comment: I think I did not understand your question. If anyone here knows digital communications and has dealt with communication channels, perhaps he can help me understand the reasoning (I'm not asking the code) behind these few steps in the picture.